# How to identify slowness lines in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku

I have a Rails app running on 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.1.3. Some times on some requests they take so long, but it doesn't happen all the times. When I check newrelic I still can't identify or trace the slowness lines.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Having similar issue, have you found the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

check out perftools - you can use googles perftools, or the [ruby specific implementation](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb).  There's a nice write-up about it [here](http://edapx.com/2014/01/20/ruby-perftools/)

It runs through your application and finds bottlenecks by determining time spent in individual method calls.  You'll get output like this:

```
Total: 23 samples
18  78.3%  78.3%      18  78.3% BigDecimal#div
4   17.4%  95.7%       4  17.4% BigDecimal#*
1   4.3%  100.0%      23 100.0% BigMath#PI
0   0.0%  100.0%      23 100.0% BigMath.PI
```

In this case, you'd need to spend some time looking at the `div` method in `BigDecimal`

Answer (score -1):

It may be a slow API call.

Here is the code for [`Doorkeeper::TokensController#create`](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb#L3-L10)

```
module Doorkeeper
  class TokensController < Doorkeeper::ApplicationMetalController
    def create
      response = strategy.authorize
      self.headers.merge! response.headers
      self.response_body = response.body.to_json
      self.status        = response.status
    rescue Errors::DoorkeeperError => e
      handle_token_exception e
    end

  # ...snip...

    private

    def strategy
      @strategy ||= server.token_request params[:grant_type]
    end
  end
end
```

I don't see any heavy lifting done in here.

---

Read this New Relic [blog post](http://blog.newrelic.com/2012/05/02/new-relic-tips-and-tricks-for-new-users/#tt) about adding [custom metrics](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/features/ruby-custom-metrics) to your code. This will replace "Application code" entries in your trace with greater detail about what is going on inside your code.

*I cannot copy the linked information here due to copyright.*

Comment: It shouldn't in TokensController#create because it doesn't happen all the time, it happened some times.

Comment: @Samnang That would make sense if the external API is normally fast but *sometimes* slow (eg. under heavy load).